# it is not running and showing indexError

Tags: python, split

```
term="gv jnj klk"
stri=[]
c=0
for i in range(0,len(term)-1):
if term[i]==" ":
 c=c+1
else:
 stri[c]=stri[c]+term[i]
print(stri)
```

error shown is
stri[c]=stri[c]+term[i]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: (1) Fix the indentation of the code. (2) Usually you should show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question. (3) "stri" is empty, any item access with an index number will fail.

Comment: Notice that your `stri` list has no values. The first run of `stri[c]=stri[c]+term[i]` aims for an `stri[0]` which does not exist.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146 and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. After you have tried to solve the problem yourself, you can show us a full error message, explain the problem clearly (including the *intended purpose* of the code), and **ask a question**, starting with a question word like "how" or "what" and ending with a question mark (`?`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use split() method on this to remove unnecessary steps. For example,

```
term="gv jnj klk"
result = term.split()
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['gv', 'jnj', 'klk']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `stri` list is empty. Try this code:

```
term="gv jnj klk"
stri=[""] * len(term)
c=0
for i in range(0,len(term)-1):
    if term[i]==" ":
        c=c+1
    else:
        stri[c]=stri[c]+term[i]
print(stri)
```

Output:

```
['gv', 'jnj', 'kl', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

I suggest you use the shorthand operator `+=`. And using the append results in preventing extra non-useful elements in your lisst. I also suggest you to add the last character after leaving the loop:

```
term="gv jnj klk"
stri=[""]
c=0
for i in range(0, len(term)-1):
    if term[i]==" ":
        c += 1
        stri.append("")
    else:
        stri[c] += term[i]
stri[-1] += term[-1]
print(stri)
```

Output:

```
['gv', 'jnj', 'klk']
```